# How to automate text file importing to Excel when column widths vary from day to day

Tags: excel

I have to import 7 text files into Excel every day.  I would like to automate the task using a macro, but the width of one of the columns may vary.  Currently I have to remove the 'automatic' breaks and insert my own (which are always at the same positions).   Is there any way to modify the Excel import wizard to NOT automatically insert the column breaks?

Comment: Please show several typical rows of your data from TXT - this will define the approach. 5-7 would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by passing an array containing the parse information into the FieldInfo parameter of the TextToColumns method.

The FieldInfo parameter takes as its value an Array containing the parse information for each individual column of data you would like the source column split into and takes the a format such as:

```
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(11, 1))
```

From [Microsoft’s documentation of the FieldInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) parameter:

> An array containing parse information for the individual columns of
>   data. The interpretation depends on the value of DataType. When the
>   data is delimited, this argument is an array of two-element arrays,
>   with each two-element array specifying the conversion options for a
>   particular column. The first element is the column number (1-based),
>   and the second element is one of the [xlColumnDataType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193030%28v=office.15%29.aspx) constants
>   specifying how the column is parsed.

So, to split the data in column 'A' of an imported file into individual columns at the positions 2, 5, 7, and 11 and for the columns to have a datatype of ‘General’ you would do the following in a Macro:

```
Columns("A:A").Select

Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(5, 1), _
    Array(7, 1), Array(11, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```